# How to verify the integrity of current Apache project downloads?

Tags: apache, solr, lucene

I want to download the [current release](http://mirror.symnds.com/software/Apache/lucene/solr/4.9.1/) of Apache Solr from the recommended mirror, but the signature files seem to be missing. The latest [archived release](http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/4.9.1/) contains the expected .asc, .md5, etc. signature files. Every other Apache project I've checked (Tomcat, Cassandra, etc.) seems to be the same way. The last time I downloaded the current release of Tomcat a few months ago I recall the signature files were there as usual. Has the location changed or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [signature files for 4.10.2 is available on the archive site](http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/4.10.2/) as well.

```
md5: a24f73f70e3fcf6aa8fda67444981f78 *solr-4.10.2.tgz
sha1: b913204d07212d7bb814afe4641992f22404a27d *solr-4.10.2.tgz

-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: GnuPG v1

iEYEABECAAYFAlRMxb0ACgkQ8RmUH25o2mHNLgCfSCHKyvLACVEYEfDLmgh+Mv2W
hvcAoJQcJ4AGiXNtM7ZRKVPu8HiIu1ic
=39HO
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```